# Incoming IP addresses for webhooks?

Tags: webhooks, copyleaks-api

What IP Address range do your webhooks come from? We need to white list them to receive your Copyleaks results to our web server.

Thank You,

Comment: This is stack overflow, copyleaks and some other sites link to stack over flow where stack overflow users can maybe answer, stack overflow does not have anything to do with copy leaks though. Does this help? https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/webhooks

Comment: Nope, I already scoured all that information and emailed the company last week. At the end of that page you reference they have this little blurb below, but I wasn't holding out too much hope because there hasn't been a lot of action specific to Copyleaks. 

Thank You...

Do you have a technical question?
Use stackoverflow.com to get help from our development team and other Copyleaks users.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Copyleaks API not arriving from fixed list of IP addresses. But, you have other alternatives to securing your endpoints. The options described here:

https://api.copyleaks.com/documentation/v3/webhooks/security

Another option you have to secure your endpoints is to add "Authentication" header to the webhook request with a private secret in its value. With Copyleaks API you have the ability to specify the headers that will arrive to your endpoints.